# How to create a new table that only keeps rows with more than 5 data records under the same id in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, rows

I have a table like this:

| Id | Date | Steps | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-06-01 | 1000 | 1 |

There are over 1000 records and 50 Ids in this table, most ids have about 20 records, and some ids only have 1, or 2 records which I think are useless.
I want to create a table that excludes those ids with less than 5 records.
I wrote this code to find the ids that I want to exclude:

```
SELECT  
  Id,
  COUNT(Id) AS num_id
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY 
  Id
ORDER BY
  num_id
```

Since there are only two ids I need to exclude, I use WHERE clause:

```
CREATE TABLE `` AS
SELECT  
  *
FROM ``
WHERE
  Id <> 2320127002
  AND Id <> 7007744171
```

Although I can get the result I want, I think there are better ways to solve this kind of problem. For example, if there are over 20 ids with less than 5 records in this table, what shall I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `filtered_table` AS
SELECT *
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE TRUE QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) >= 5
```

Note: You can remove `WHERE TRUE` if it runs successfully without it.